# Date conversion resulting in NULL in hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

The birthday field is returning NULL when fetching the data from the underlying table when i do an insert. The underlying table in the INSERT statement (XYZ) got birthday in number format like '20030131'. I've tried to cast that to string and applied date functions but that isn't working. How can i get my birthday fields to it's right shape? I would consider any technical advise on this very as very precious.

```
I want my date to be in dd/mm/yyyy

what i tried 

" CAST(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIMESTAMP(CAST(BIRTHDAY AS STRING), 'DD/MM/YYY') AS DATE) AS BIRTHDAY "

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table
(
-SOME OTHER FIELDS,
name varchar(255),
birthday date
)

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE test_table
SELECT
-SOME OTHER FIELDS,
NAME,
CAST(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIMESTAMP(CAST(BIRTHDAY AS STRING), 'DD/MM/YYY') AS DATE) AS BIRTHDAY
FROM
XYZ

My results:

| name | birthday |
|gorge | NULL |
|rake  | NULL |
```

Comment: Something about this is off, the `()` don't add up. There are more `(` than `)`....

Comment: I don't know HIve. It sounds like maybe: `TO_DATE(CAST(BIRTHDAY AS CHAR(8)), 'YYYYMMDD')`

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert but ussually when i want to formate a date i use TO_DATE() function some thing like

`TO_DATE(BIRTHDAY, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as BIRTHDAY`

if that doesnt work maybe something here may help
https://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_TODATE